# ORA-00907 missing right parenthesis in a SELECT

Tags: oracle

I struggled for a while with this error in a SELECT statement; a quick search brought up several posts with the same error, but it's quite a generic error and none described this particular case.

```
select 'hello' as some_value,
 (
   select min(table_name) from user_tables order by table_name
 ) as min_tab
from dual;
```

```
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 3 Column: 44
```

Why?
(of course it's obvious now I've boiled it down to a minimal example)

Answer (score 2):

The error is quite unhelpful, all it really means is that something else occurred at a point in the SQL where a right parenthesis would have been the only valid thing.

Here, the problem is the `ORDER BY` which is not legal in this position.

```
select 'hello' as some_value,
 (
   select min(table_name) from user_tables
 ) as min_tab
from dual;
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove `ORDER BY` clause, it is useless in this context.

Comment: Yup, I thought I would post as a question since although I already found the answer (and it's obvious in this short example) it can be hard to find in a longer request.

Comment: Ah, so you created some kind of a FAQ. OK.

Comment: yes, this is an encouraged behaviour for SO as far as I can understand

Comment: No problem with me. I just saw the question and answered it :)